# Merge two subqueries into one in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Is there a best way to make this SELECT statement with these two subqueries ?

```
SELECT N.ID, N.NAME 
   (SELECT TR.PUZZLE 
    FROM puzzles TR
    WHERE TR.TEAMID = "152" 
      AND TR.NID= N.ID) AS PUZZLE_OK,
   (SELECT TR.PUZZLE_BIS 
    FROM puzzles TR
    WHERE TR.TEAMID = "152" 
      AND TR.NID= N.ID) AS PUZZLE_BIS_OK
FROM news N
WHERE N.SERIESID = "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query using a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT N.ID, N.NAME, TR.PUZZLE AS PUZZLE_OK, TR.PUZZLE_BIS AS PUZZLE_BIS_OK
FROM news N
JOIN puzzles TR ON TR.NID = N.ID
WHERE N.SERIESID = "1"
  AND TR.TEAMID = "152"
```

Note that if it's possible no entry in `puzzles` exists for a given `ID` value from `news`, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` and move the `WHERE` condition on `puzzles` into the `JOIN`. This will then return `NULL` values for `PUZZLE_OK` and `PUZZLE_BIS_OK` in the same way as your subqueries will:

```
SELECT N.ID, N.NAME, TR.PUZZLE AS PUZZLE_OK, TR.PUZZLE_BIS AS PUZZLE_BIS_OK
FROM news N
LEFT JOIN puzzles TR ON TR.NID = N.ID AND TR.TEAMID = "152"
WHERE N.SERIESID = "1"
```

Note I've changed the alias on `news` to `N` to keep the `SELECT` clause consistent with what was in the subqueries in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think about JOIN.

Comment: I've tried with LEFT JOIN before to add my answer. I don't know we could add some extra after a LEFT JOIN ... ON ... with AND

Comment: @Padd When using a `LEFT JOIN` it's actually *necessary* to include conditions such as `TR.TEAMID = "152"` into the join condition, otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)